# enable/disable functionality buttons based on radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the page loads a table with radio buttons is displayed. below the table 3 buttons X, Y, Z are disabled. When the user selects a radio button from the table only then these three buttons X, Y, Z should be enabled?

Comment: I'm unclear what you're asking. Are you asking if buttons should be enabled, or how to enable them?

Answer (score 4):

Javascript:

```
$('table input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    $('input[type="button"]').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" />...
...

<input type="button" disabled ... />
```

Comment: For the benefit of the OP, they should consider using ID selectors, or CSS selectors so that every button on the page doesn't get enabled when you click on any radio button.

Comment: This answer will add an onclick listener to all raido buttons, including the disabled ones, which doesn't seem suitable. In order for radio buttons to be grouped, they must share a common name (omitted from the example), so it makes more sense to select them by name. It also seems reasonable that if no radio buttons are selected (which should not be allowed to happen but many web pages ignore good design principles) then the X, Y and Z buttons should be disabled again. And having been disabled, if any are checked they should probably also be unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

A listener can be attached to the table and the radio button set can be referenced by name. When a click event occurs on a radio button in the table, the X, Y and Z buttons can be enabled or disabled based on whether any buttons in a particular group are checked or not. The logic needs to allow for cases where the form is reset, e.g.

```
<form>
  <table id="table0" style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="group1">
      <td><input type="radio" name="group1">
      <td><input type="radio" name="group1">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="reset">
      <td>
      <td>
  </table>
  <label for="r2-0">X&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="group2" id="r2-0" value="x"></label>
  <label for="r2-1">Y&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="group2" id="r2-1" value="y"></label>
  <label for="r2-2">Z&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="group2" id="r2-2" value="z"></label>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function enableButtons() {
  var buttons1 = document.getElementsByName('group1');
  var buttons2 = document.getElementsByName('group2');
  var checkedState = false;

  // Check if any buttons in group 1 have been checked
  for (var i=0, iLen=buttons1.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (buttons1[i].checked) {
      checkedState = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  // Enable or disable group 2 buttons based on above result
  // When disabling, also uncheck any that are checked
  for (var j=0, jLen=buttons2.length; j<jLen; j++) {
    if (!checkedState) {
      buttons2[j].checked = false;
      buttons2[j].disabled = true;
    } else {
      buttons2[j].disabled = false;
    }
  }
}

window.onload = function() {

  // Disable X, Y & Z buttons
  var buttons = document.getElementsByName('group2');
  for (var i=0, iLen=buttons.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    buttons[i].disabled = true;
  }

  // Add onlick listener to table
  var table  = document.getElementById('table0');
  if (table) table.onclick = function() {
    window.setTimeout(enableButtons, 1);
  }
}

</script>
```